# Ubuntu 18.04 starts automatically after hibernate

Tags: dual-boot, hibernate

This is the first time I install ubuntu in dual boot with windows. I've been having some trouble trying to make hibernate work properly.

Right now it seems to work, when I click the button it goes to hibernate, then the computer seems to shut down, but (after 1 or 2 seconds) it reboots automatically showing all the applications open.

---

After some troubleshooting I ended up finding that the responsible was the keyboard. It does work perfectly when the keyboard is unplugged, even thought I don't press any key.

Does anyone know how I could solve it?

Comment: HIbernate? Or suspend/sleep? Big difference.

Comment: No, I'm trying to hibernate